# How can I prevent SlideView from undoing column spacings?

Tags: slideshows, spacing, column

I am putting together a presentation with `SlideView`. Within many of the slides I have calls to `Column` using the `Spacings` option to adjust, well, the vertical spacings between elements.  It seems however, that when wrapped inside `SlideView`, those spacings are completely undone, destroying what I am trying to show.

(In my case, I am using `Column` with seriously compressed spacings to display information compactly within the `VertexRenderingFunction` of a `LayeredGraphPlot`. All works beautifully when stand alone. However, when then simply wrapped in a `SlideShow`, rendering of the `LayeredGraphPlot` is destroyed: the vertices blow up, becoming so huge they totally cover each other, the graph structure, etc.)

Here is a snippet of code that shows the problem:

```
Row @ Table[
  Row @ {
    Framed @ Column[{1, 2, 3}, Center, Spacings -> vspace]
    , SlideView[{
      Framed @ Column[{1, 2, 3}, Center, Spacings -> vspace]}]
    , "   "},
  {vspace, {0, 1, 2}}]
```

Here is a picture of the output.

[image]

BTW, I've tried doing the layout with explicit vertical positioning of various `Text` and other `Graphics` elements over a `Rectangle` within the `VertexRenderingFunction`.  This however requires knowing explicit rendered sizes of each element so they can be packed closely, and the surrounding `Rectangle` made the appropriate size. Those sizes change from instance to instance of the `LayeredGraphPlot`, so I can't just do it once and for all by hand. Doing it automatically, e.g., with `Rasterize[thing, "RasterSize"]` has proved surprisingly troublesome, but that is another issue...

I'm using Mathematica 10.4

Comment: You can use `Grid[List /@ {1, 2, 3}, Spacings -> {Automatic, vspace}]` till we crack the problem.

Comment: Maybe adding Spacer can help

Comment: The `Grid` workaround will certainly work for now. Thanks.

Comment: To close voters, what is a simple mistake here?

Answer (score 3):

For some reason (I suspect a bug), you must give the `Spacings` specification that is wrapped by `SlideView` in full form; i.e., a list of two elements. If you do that it will work.

```
Row @
  Table[
    Row @
      {Framed @ Column[{1, 2, 3}, Center, Spacings -> vspace], 
       SlideView[
         {Framed @ Column[{1, 2, 3}, Center, Spacings -> {Automatic, vspace}]}], 
       "   "},
    {vspace, {0, 1, 2}}]
```

[image: views]

Comment: I find this problem interesting because it overwrites options given explicitly to the function, from outside. This is useful if it is general. Didn't have time to dig though.